# Understanding the future of the .NET framework

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, cross-platform

I currently use Qt for my desktop app (simple apps) development. The one thing I don’t like about Qt is the fact that I have a feeling that the free license will eventually disappear and I would rather move to a different framework. On the other side I have been hearing about .NET going open source and cross platform.

Can someone clarify what exactly does this means because I have read that only the server side will be open sourced and cross platform but I’m not sure if this will only affect Linux servers.

1. Does this mean that we will be able to create cross platform application in Visual Studio?
2. Does this means that Visual Studio will run on Linux and Mac?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This link should provide insight: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/announcing-open-source-of-net-core-framework-net-core-distribution-for-linux-osx-and-free-visual-studio-community-edition?WT.mc_id=11194-bznl-dec-us-ns-2

Comment: 1. Yes - 2. No, rather unlikely. The whole idea is to enable ASP.NET 5 applications to be hosted on other platforms - not just Windows and IIS - to make them cross-platform. But that's the **ASP.NET** runtime and applications. Visual Studio on Mac is in my opinion highly unlikely - VS just uses way too many Windows-specific features (like WPF for its GUI) to make it portable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In December I got an email from BizSpark about this very same announcement.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/announcing-open-source-of-net-core-framework-net-core-distribution-for-linux-osx-and-free-visual-studio-community-edition

Basically, the idea is to open-source the **ASP.NET** runtimes to allow developers to build **ASP.NET** websites for all platforms.

That said, there's no telling where Microsoft will take it. My personal opinion is that they will use this opportunity to port the *ENTIRE* **.NET** framework to Linux/OS X, but this is complete conjecture.

> Today I’m excited to announce that we are going even further, and will be open sourcing the .NET Core Runtime.  This will include everything needed to execute .NET code – including the CLR, Just-In-Time Compiler (JIT), Garbage Collector (GC), and core .NET base class libraries.

And more importantly:

> Today’s open source announcement means that developers will have a fully supported, fully open source, fully cross platform .NET stack for creating **server and cloud applications** – including everything from the **C#/VB compilers**, to the **CLR runtime**, to the core **.NET base class libraries**, to the higher-level **.NET Web, Data and API** frameworks.

You should visit the GitHub page for **.NET** and see what it has to offer, as this will likely be the first part of **.NET** to be cross-platformed: https://github.com/dotnet/

So, to answer your questions:

1. To an *extent*. The entire **.NET** framework is **NOT** expected to be ported (largely `System.Windows`, and the other *GUI* libraries). You will likely **NOT** be able to develop `WPF` or `Windows Forms` apps for Linux/OS X, but **WILL** be able to develop `ASP.NET WebForms and MVC` products for them.
2. ***Not** likely*. Visual Studio is expected to remain a Windows-only application.

Edit: Yes, you could continue to use **MONO** or **WINE** for *GUI* based applications, and yes, large parts of the **MONO** and **WINE** implementations could be based around the new open-sourcing of the **.NET** framework, but if you are expecting *Visual Studio* to allow you to compile Linux/Unix/OS X native applications, you will likely not find that in the new announcements.

Answer (score 1):

The .net framework is cross platform (similar to java's JVM, it's all managed code), allowing you to develop apps that will run on linux/mac/ios/android, but I don't know if you'll ever be able to run visual studio on anything other than windows (could install windows on your mac machine and switch to it).

There are cross platform IDEs for .net though, like Mono. If you search for them you'll find a few options.

This was just posted today 5/1 (VisualStudioMagazine) and I thought I would add this when I remembered your post:

"You probably never thought you would see the day when Visual Studio would run natively on a Mac. Well the newest member to the Visual Studio family, Visual Studio Code, does just that. Visual Studio Code is a lightweight code editor that has versions that will run on Windows, Mac, and Linux. But don't let the fact that it is lightweight fool you. It is packed with a ton of features like full Intellisense, color coding, and more. Even better, it's free."

Answer (score 1):

> Does this means that we will be able to create cross platform application in Visual Studio?

Yes. There are a variety of third party user interface frameworks that can be used to develop open source applications. None of them are officially supported by Microsoft as far as I know, aside from Silverlight which is deprecated.

[WinForms](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/) does work under Mono and can be used to deliver applications which work in Linux and Mac but last I tried, it was a bit buggy. It's probably better now but if you use it you will want to test early and test often on multiple platforms. The desktop experience also feels rather foreign, especially on Mac. Also, you only have designer support in Visual Studio on Windows. But it does work.

There is also [GTK#](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/) which is free (in both senses). This provides a significantly more native feel to apps, not 100% perfect but pretty good. There is designer support in MonoDevelop for it and there are external tools which you can use to design user interfaces that you can then load in your application.

[Xwt](https://github.com/mono/xwt) is free, and looks promising and is actively developed. I haven't looked at it in a while. This one is apparently used by Xamarin Studio and MonoDevelop, so it is probably fairly robust.

[Eto.Forms](https://github.com/picoe/Eto) is another free one that looks promising, and includes support for mobile development. I haven't looked at it much at all and it doesn't look like it's been actively developed lately.

> Does this means that Visual Studio will run on Linux and Mac?

No. This seems extremely unlikely. Wine seems to have made [some progress on some older versions of Visual Studio](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=892) but you will not likely be able to use any recent version of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

With [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) you can create cross-platform applications, and even GUI with [WinForms](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/) or [Gtk#](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/), you can develop them and compile in **Visual Studio** under .net (we know that mono is just a reimplementation of .net) but in **Linux** you will have to run them under mono. I think Mono has a good future now that Microsoft has made their new compiler [open-source](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) so it will simplify development of mono-project.

I don't think that visual studio will be available in **Linux** or **Mac** because it would be a huge work to port them on those platforms. If you just want an **IDE** for developing on another platform you can use [MonoDevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/) but it is not so rich as visual studio

Answer (score 0):

**Breaking news:**  This just in from Scott Hunter, Director of .NET Program Management:

> All future investment in .NET will be in .NET Core. This includes:
>   Runtime, JIT, AOT, GC, BCL (Base Class Library), C#, VB.NET, F#,
>   ASP.NET, Entity Framework, ML.NET, WinForms, WPF and Xamarin.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-is-the-future-of-net/